# forEach javascript function not defined

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am trying to implement the forEach javascript function to iterate through the `players` array and total up some values. When I call the function, I get the error

```
players.forEach(function(players){
    ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The code is here:

```
/*calculate the total number of points per player, use to calculate total score*/
function playerTotal(playerObj){
  var pacersTotal = 0;
  var hawksTotal = 0;
  var total = 0;
  total += 3*(playerObj.three_pointers_made);
  total += 2*(playerObj.field_goals_made - playerObj.three_pointers_made);
  total += playerObj.free_throws_made;
  if (playerObj.team_name == "Pacers"){
    pacersTotal += total;
  }
  else {
    hawksTotal += total;
  }
  console.log("Pacers " + pacersTotal + "\nHawks" + hawksTotal);
}

players.forEach(playerTotal(players));
```

In other words, I try to call the `playerTotal` function on each value (object) in the `players` array using forEach, but no avail! Any tips?

Comment: You never defined the array `players`, did you?

Comment: Where does `players` come from?

Comment: You show **two** calls to `forEach` in the above, one which (although only part of it is shown) looks correct-ish (at the top, though the argument name is off), another which is incorrect (at the bottom). Which are you using?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you have defined `players` before invoking `forEach` method on it, **problem** is this line

```
players.forEach(playerTotal(players));
```

It should be passed **function reference** not the **function response**.

make it

```
players.forEach(function(playerObj){

   playerTotal(playerObj);

});
```

Comment: Assuming that's actually in their code, as opposed to the one shown at the top of the question. But it fits the error message, just not the code where that error message is shown in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true, `players.forEach(function(players){` is different from  `players.forEach(playerTotal(players));`. I assumed the latter since that looks more likely looking at the error.

Comment: Yes, it fits the error message provided, whereas `players` being undefined, or `players.forEach` being undefined, doesn't fit the quoted error message.

Comment: I defined the array players. (It's just quite large, so I didn't include that part of the code.) The error was originally being thrown for the line `players.forEach(playerTotal(players));`  As suggested by @gurvinder372, I updated it to `players.forEach(function(playerObj){

   playerTotal(playerObj);

});` but am still getting the same error.